# Why can we not iterate over a variable outside the scope of the "with" statement in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am a bit new to learning python, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes.

I have recently learned about the "with" statement in python along with it's corresponding use in safely and properly opening and closing files. From what I understand one cannot read/write from a file after the "with" statement block i.e all reading and writing of files must be constrained to within the "with" statement block.

I have also read that one can store the contents of a file within a variable and use such a variable outside of the "with" statement's scope. For instance, in the example below, if you were to store the iterable object produced from reading a CSV file in a variable, you can still print out the iterable object outside of the "with" statement scope:

```
import csv

with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

print(temp_var) # Prints out a DictReader Object containing data from the CSV file
```

```
import csv

with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

for i in temp_var:
    print(i) # Produces a 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'
```

However, when one tries to iterate over the DictReader object from the example above outside of the "with" statement scope we get an error saying "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." as shown below

```
import csv

with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

for i in temp_var:
    print(i) # Produces a 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'
```

It seems like this error of "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." also seems to occur when I try to pass the DictReader object into a function outside of the "with" statement's scope, as shown below:

```
import csv

with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

temp_list = list(temp_var) # Produces a 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'
```

The only way to bypass the "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." is to place the iteration portion within the scope of the "with" statement, as shown below

```
import csv

with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

for i in temp_var:
    print(i) # Produces a 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'
```

I am curious as to why such an error occurs i.e why can we print a variable outside the "with" statement scope that is defined within the "with" statement's scope, but not iterate over it? and I am open to suggestions about how I could overcome this error.

Thanking you in advance.

To solve this problem I have searched up why the "with" statement produces the "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." and all I found were a few answers expression that it is convention to always iterate within the scope of the "with" statement. However, I have never understood why we are allowed to print a variable outside the "with" statement's scope but iterate outside of it. Intuitively I believe that one must be able to iterate over a variable outside of the "with" statement's scope if they can print it outside of the "with" statement's scope, but there must some level of explanation that must be beyond me

Comment: That’s what `with` is *for.* It closes the file when its scope exits. No mystery.

Comment: I don't understand why I can still print the variable even after the scope exits, but not iterate over it

Comment: The variable is still defined and refers to the object assigned to it by the `with` statement. What changes is the *state* of that object following the `with` statement.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'state' of the object

Comment: In this particular case, `DictReader` is lazy. It does not immediately read the contents of `f` into memory; it just *holds* the reference so that when you do something that requires more data, it reads from the file at that moment. If you try to use the `DictReader` after the `with` statement, the underlying file has been closed and you can't read from it anymore.

Comment: So in this case, you need to understand the semantics of the particular context manager being used, not just how `with` statements work in general.

Comment: In short, the instance of `DictReader` persists beyond the `with` statement, but it is only (fully) usable *inside* the `with` statement, because it relies on the file-like object opened and closed by the `with` statement.

Comment: Perhaps more specifically: you *can* iterate over the object (you didn't get a "object not iterable" error), but something that the iterator tries to do *during* iteration failed.

Comment: Oh, so the reason why I can't iterate over it is because the reference to the file is gone, so the DictReader cannot read anything

Comment: _I don't understand why I can still print the variable even after the scope exits, but not iterate over it_ It's the difference between reading the label printed on the outside of a box, and trying to open the box to see what's inside.

Comment: The variable _exists_, but it doesn't _contain_ anything.

Comment: @SiddharthVadyalam no, the reference to the file is still there. But the *file is closed*, which is what the file object context manager *is meant to do*. That's the whole point.

Comment: IOW, if you did `f = open("some_file_that_exists.txt")` then `file.close()` then `file.readline()` you'd get the *same error*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" error occurs because, when you use the with statement to open a file, the file is automatically closed when the block of code inside the with statement is exited. This is done to ensure proper resource management and to avoid potential issues with file handling.

In your example, when you do the following:

```
with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

# The file 'example_file.csv' is closed at this point

for i in temp_var:
    print(i)  # Produces a 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'
```

The temp_var object is essentially a CSV reader object that depends on the file f. When the with block is exited, the file is closed, and any subsequent attempt to read from it will result in an error.

Now, when you do:

```
with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)

print(temp_var)  # Prints out a DictReader Object containing data from the CSV file
```

In this case, you are just printing the representation of the temp_var object, which doesn't require reading from the file. It's essentially showing you information about the object itself, not the file it's associated with. However, when you try to iterate over temp_var outside the 'with' block, it attempts to read from the closed file, leading to the 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'

To overcome this, you should perform any file-related operations, such as iteration, within the scope of the with statement. If you need to work with the data outside that scope, you can store it in a data structure (e.g., a list) and then operate on that structure later:

```
import csv

data_list = []

with open('example_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    temp_var = csv.DictReader(f)
    data_list.extend(temp_var)

# Now you can work with data_list outside the with block
for i in data_list:
    print(i)
```

This way, you've read the data into data_list while the file is still open, and you can perform operations on it outside the with block without encountering the 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.'